# How to do python style string slicing in c++

Tags: python, c++, object-slicing

Is it possible to implement a method through which I can do slicing in C++ using `:` operator.

For example,I define a C-style string as shown below:

```
char my_name[10] {"InAFlash"};
```

Can I implement a function or override any internal method to do the following:

```
cout << my_name[1:5] << endl;
```

> Output: `nAFl`

Update 1: i tried with string type as below

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string my_name;
    my_name = "Hello";
    // strcpy(my_name[2,5],"PAD");
    // my_name[2]='p';
    cout << my_name[2:4];
    return 0;
}
```

But, got the following error

```
helloWorld.cpp: In function 'int main()':
helloWorld.cpp:10:22: error: expected ']' before ':' token
     cout << my_name[2:4];
                      ^
helloWorld.cpp:10:22: error: expected ';' before ':' token
```

Comment: Have you looked at `std::string`? `char[10]` would be the C way to go.

Comment: yes, i got this error `helloWorld.cpp:12:22: error: expected ';' before ':' token`

Comment: C++ doesn't support this syntax. You need to use a different syntax. `std::string` has a function `substr` that does what you want. If you need `:`, use Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a copy of the string, then it can be done using iterators or `substr`:

```
std::string my_name("InAFlash");
std::string slice = my_name.substr(1, 4); // Note this is start index, count
```

If you want to slice it without creating a new string, then `std::string_view` (C++17) would be the way to go:

```
std::string_view slice(&my_name[0], 4);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are stuck with C-style array, [`std::string_view` (C++17)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view) could be a good way to manipulate `char[]` without copying memory around:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string_view>

int main()
{
    char my_name[10] {"InAFlash"};
    std::string_view peak(my_name+1, 4);
    std::cout << peak << '\n'; // prints "nAFl"
}
```

Demo: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fa3dbaf385fd53c5

---

With `std::string`, a copy would be necessary:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    char my_name[10] {"InAFlash"};
    std::string peak(my_name+1, 4);
    std::cout << peak << '\n'; // prints "nAFl"
}
```

Demo: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a16112ac3ffcd8de

Answer (score 1):

If you use `std::string` (the C++ way) you can

```
std::string b = a.substr(1, 4);
```